# Convert bash script to powershell 5

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and I want to convert this linux command

```
curl -v -X POST \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
-F upload=@"C:\path\to\file\blah.postman_collection.json" \
-F ScanName="postman_scan1" \
http://localhost:8083/webinspect/APIScanner/Postman/startPostmanScan
```

I have the following command but I don't know how to place the json file to send it in the request or if what I have so far will be fine

```
$body = '@{
 "ContentType" = "multipart/form-data"
 "accept" = "application/json"
 "ScanName"="postman_scan1"
 }'


Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -Body $body
```

Comment: Windows has curl.exe. Is there a reason that cannot be used? Or, is this an exercise?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with what you're trying to achieve, but have a look at the below. This might help or might not.

```
$Url = "http://localhost:8083/webinspect/APIScanner/Postman/startPostmanScan"
$filePath = "C:\path\to\file\blah.postman_collection.json"
$ScanName = "postman_scan1"

# Create a multipart/form-data request
$body = [ordered]@{
    ScanName = $ScanName
}
$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath)
$fileBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileBytes)
$body.Add("upload", $fileBase64)

# Set headers
$headers = @{
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}

# Send the request
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body

# Display the response
$response
```